# Projective and injective resolutions of cyclic modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module, injective-module

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a cyclic $R$-module. It is well-known that always exist projective and injective resolutions of $M$. Is it any method to construct explicitly these resolutions which have the minimal length ?

Comment: First of all, the resolutions can be infinite. Second, what do you mean by "*explicitly*"?

Comment: Right, the resolution can be infinite. Assume that there exists a finite resolution. Can we construct explicitly resolution which have the minimal length ? Explicitly means without theorems of existence. For some modules $M$ we know that there must be resolution of length smaller than some $d$. My question is : can we find resolution which minimizes the length if $M$ is cyclic ?